# appending to a list of lists

Tags: python, list, append

I want to add an additional time of '10:01' for J Petry to the following list:

```
PlayerMatrix = [["['J. Petry', '24:17']"], ["['G. Chase', '11:03']"]]
```

so I want to get output of ......

```
PlayerMatrix = [["['J. Petry', '24:17', '10:01']"], ["['G. Chase', '11:03']"]]
```

I've tried

```
PlayerMatrix[0].append("10:01")
```

and this gives me.......

```
PlayerMatrix = [["['J. Petry', '24:17']", '10:01'], ["['G. Chase', '11:03']"]]
```

ie instead of adding it to the first list it creates a second list. There must be something simple I'm doing wrong.....

Comment: Your first "list" isn't a `list` but rather a `string`

Comment: It is strange you have string representations of lists.  Are you sure this is correct?

Answer (score 1):

As your element are string you can not use `append` for this aim . you can use `ast` module :

```
>>> import ast
>>> a=ast.literal_eval(PlayerMatrix[0][0])
>>> a
['J. Petry', '24:17']
>>> a.append("10:01")
>>> a
['J. Petry', '24:17', '10:01']
```

and then you can convert the result to string :

```
>>> str(a)
"['J. Petry', '24:17', '10:01']"
```

Comment: I didn't know about `ast.literal_eval`, nice answer. +1

Comment: @FamousSam you're welcome , if you find this answer helpful you can tell this to community by accepting the answer and voting.

Answer (score 0):

Odd format you have there. The solution:

```
PlayerMatrix = [["['J. Petry', '24:17']"], ["['G. Chase', '11:03']"]]
# used to serialize/deserialize - probably should have functions for that
import json
def append_to_player(matrix, player, t):
    # parse your format
    parsed = [json.loads(v[0].replace("'", '"')) for v in matrix]
    for p in parsed:
        # add the value to 'player'
        if p[0] == player:
            p.append(t)
    # reformat and return
    return [[json.dumps(v).replace('"', "'")] for v in parsed]

# TEST
# alter matrix by assignment of result
PlayerMatrix = append_to_player(PlayerMatrix, "J. Petry", '13;37')
print PlayerMatrix
```

Comment: Thanks - appreciated hugely